# Django-Filter: Dynamically Create Queryset on Search or Hide Queryset until Search

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-filter

I am using `django-filter` to search a model. Here is the code:

filters.py:

```
class PersonFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    lastName = django_filters.CharFilter(lookup_expr='icontains')
    firstName = django_filters.CharFilter(lookup_expr='icontains')
    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = ['lastName', 'firstName']
```

views.py:

```
def search(request):
    people = Person.objects.all()
    people = PersonFilter(request.GET, queryset=people)
    context = {'filter': people}
    return render(request, 'myapp/template.html', context)
```

template.html:

```
<form method="get">
    {{ filter.form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit">Search</button>
  </form>
  <table>
  {% for field in filter.qs %}
  <tr>
    <td>
      {{ field.idno }}
    </td>
    <td>
      {{ field.lastName }}
    </td>
    <td>
      {{ field.firstName }}
    </td>
    <td>
      {{ field.status }}
    </td>
  </tr>
  {% endfor %}
</table>
{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

Right now, this results in a table that mirrors my model with search boxes for first name and last name. The search works perfectly.

How do I prevent the table of data from showing up initially? Logically, this could be done superficially (hide) or, better yet, substantially (dynamically create queryset). Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can leverage the FilterSet's `is_bound` property, although you would need to change the view code to only provide the request query params when the form has been submitted.

```py
def search(request):
    submitted = 'submitted' in request.GET
    data = request.GET if submitted else None
    people = PersonFilter(data, queryset=Person.objects.all())

    return render(request, 'myapp/template.html', {'filter': people})
```

```
<form method="get">
    {{ filter.form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit" name="submitted">Search</button>
                     <!-- ^^^^ added 'name' parameter -->
</form>

{% if filter.is_bound %}
<table>
{% for person in filter.qs %}
...
```